# Generating reports for tests in django

Tags: django, testing, report

I am using django.test.TestCase based class methods for testing of my django application. When I execute the tests, it only shows the number of tests that are passed. What should I do to get output of which test got passed and which failed on console, just like the output of Proboscis framework. 
http://packages.python.org/proboscis/

That generates output like that..

```
$ python run_tests.py

test_should_return_false_for_positive_numbers (tests.examples.unit.tests.unit.TestIsNegative) ... ok
test_should_return_false_for_zero (tests.examples.unit.tests.unit.TestIsNegative) ... ok
test_should_return_true_for_negative_numbers (tests.examples.unit.tests.unit.TestIsNegative) ... ok
Make sure our complex string reversal logic works. ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

But proboscis do not capture tests based on django.tests.TestCase class. Please advice me on what should I do now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run tests with `verbosity` option

```
python manage.py test --verbosity=2 app1 app2

-v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                    Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                    2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
```